# QT multimedia dvb ts file

Tags: qt, multimedia

I try to open some ts sample files with this sample code below;
code is ok for casual video formats but with ts file qt cant play the media.
is there a way to play ts file under qt multimedia
The code I used;

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    file=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                      tr("Video Dosyası Seç"),
                                      QDir::currentPath(),
                                      tr("Hepisi(*.*)"));
    ui->lineEdit->setText(QFile(file).fileName());
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    if(file.isNull())
    {
        QMessageBox::warning(this,
                             tr("Dosya Seç"),
                             tr("Dosya Seçilmedi"));
        return;
    }
    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(file));
    player->play();

}
```

Comment: That depends on the backend used by qtmultimeida. Which operating system are you on?

Comment: Yes right but there is no information on qt documents how we can choose streams in container.